# What is wrong with wait() on father process in pipeline

Tags: c, concurrency, process, pipeline

I have been asked:

1. What is wrong in the next code?
2. How to fix it in son's process code:

```c
#define BUF_SIZE 4096
int my_pipe[2];
pipe(my_pipe);
char buf[BUF_SIZE];
int status = fork();

//Filled buf with message...
if (status == 0) {  /* son process */
    close(my_pipe[0]);
    write(my_pipe[1],buf,BUF_SIZE*sizeof(char));
    exit(0);
 }
 else {    /* father process */
    close(my_pipe[1]);
    wait(&status);  /* wait until son process finishes */
    read(my_pipe[0], buf, BUF_SIZE*sizeof(char));
    printf("Got from pipe: %s\n", father_buff);
    exit(0);
 }
}
```

So I came up with the next code to try and conduct the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 6

int main() {
    int my_pipe[2];
    pipe(my_pipe);

    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    int status = fork();
    //Filled buf with message...
    for (int i = 0; i < BUF_SIZE; i++) buf[i] = 'a';

    if (status == 0) {    /* son process */
        close(my_pipe[0]);
        write(my_pipe[1], buf, BUF_SIZE * sizeof(char));
        _exit(0);
    } else {    /* father process */
        close(my_pipe[1]);
        wait(&status);    /* wait until son process finishes */
        printf("Son Status: %d\n", status);
        read(my_pipe[0], buf, BUF_SIZE * sizeof(char));
        printf("Got from pipe: %s\n", buf);
        _exit(0);
    }
}
```

My first thoughts were that there is a problem with the `wait(&status)`, which may cause the program not to terminate if the son process won't finish.

In the son's code, I believe if there is not enough space in the pipe, the `write` will block the process, and therefore block the whole application.

If my claims are right, how can I prove it? And I didn't figure out how to fix son's code.

Comment: I suggest you add some error checking on all your system calls. What does e.g. `read` *return*? If it returns `-1` then check `errno` to see what error you have.

Comment: `read()` before `wait()` in the parent process, and check for return codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions about the pipe size are right, I could reproduce the problem with a `BUF_SIZE` of `0x10000`.

But the solution is not on the client's but on the parent's side. You just have to `read()` before `wait()` and of course you should always use the return code to determine how much you have received. This fix of the parent didn't cause blocks anymore:

```
    len = read(my_pipe[0], buf, BUF_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    if( len >= 0 ) {
            printf("Got %d from pipe\n", len );
    } else {
            perror( "read()" );
    }
    close(my_pipe[1]);
    wait(&status);    /* wait until son process finishes */
    printf("Son Status: %d\n", status);
```

In the child process you could use non-blocking IO using `fcntl(my_pipe[1], F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);` so `write()` would send as much as possible and then return. Of course the rest of the data would be lost in that case.

Comment: This + the value of `BUF_SIZE` are the only changes I've made. Maybe on your system you have to increase the value of `BUF_SIZE` even more

Comment: in fact, I've just checked on another machine and I needed `BUF_SIZE` `0x20000` for the problen to occur

Comment: Yea I get it, but the `BUF_SIZE` is a variable, I believe I can't change it, so with `BUF_SIZE` of `4096` can I somehow block the process?

Comment: not sure if there's a way to manipulate the buffer size of a pipe.

Comment: but coming back to your original question: "What is wrong in the next code?" -- as long as you can't be sure that the code will *never* run on a machine where `BUF_SIZE` exceeds the pipe buffer, the code *is* wrong, even if you have to manipulate the actual values to prove it